# merge function not adding values from other dataframe giving NaN instead of df values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe df

```
Range       Tc      Min     Max Filter
700         80      0       10  AB
800         40      0       10  AB
700-800     80-40   0       12  AB
900                             AB
1400                            AB
1800        288     0.5     10  AB
2100        100     0.5     10  AB
2300                            AB
2600        200     0       10  AB
3400-3600   120     0       9   AB
```

df1

```
Sy      af    power   fr
1400    80      0     1
1800    40      40    1.5
2100    60      40    1.5
2300    0       120   0.5
2600    140     60    0.5
3400    60      60    0
700     0       40    1
800     40      40    1
900     110     110   1
```

Here i tried to map the values from df1 to df but it is giving me NaN values for all columns in df2 after merging
Note: 1.Range has unique values it should be repeated for the Filter like AB,AC,EG...etc
2. df1 is the mapping sheet for me, so these values i need to match with df and add columns af,power,fr to df of Range values.

output as below

```
Range       Tc      Min     Max Filter  af    power   fr        
700         80      0       10  AB      0       40     1        
800         40      0       10  AB      40      40     1    
700-800     80-40   0       12  AB      NaN     NaN    NaN
900                             AB      110     110    1        
1400                            AB      80      0      1        
1800        288     0.5     10  AB      40      40     1.5      
2100        100     0.5     10  AB      60      40     1.5      
2300                            AB      0       120    0.5      
2600        200     0       10  AB      140     60     0.5  
3400-3600   120     0       9   AB      NaN     NaN     NaN
```

i have used following map method but it is giving NaN values df1

df['TotalMax'] = df['Range'].map(df1.set_index('Sy')['af'])

used merge left_on even this is also giving me NaN values in my newdf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Range` and `Sy` are set as strings. Make sure there are no leading/trailing blanks or hidden characters.

```
df['Range'] = df['Range'].astype(str).replace(r'[^\d\-]', '', regex=True)
df1['Sy']   = df1['Sy'].astype(str).replace(r'[^\d\-]', '', regex=True)

df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', left_on='Range', right_on='Sy')
```

Comment: Yup, i tried this one also i have converted entire df into object and still i am getting NaN values after merging df with df1

Comment: Could there be leading/trailing blanks or other hidden characters in `Range` or `Sy`? Try `df['Range'] = df['Range'].str.replace(r'[^0-9\-]', '', regex=True)` and `df1['Sy'] = df1['Sy'].str.replace(r'[^0-9\-]', '', regex=True)`, then merge.